# nodejs - pkg. CLI doubles input

Tags: javascript, node.js, pkg-config

There is this weird things happening with my computer. I made a little game with Nodejs and turned it into a .exe with PKG. and it works. except there is this odd thing were when i lunch it on my laptop, the program lunches in a terminal (normal) opens the input with a readline (normal) but when he ask  the question, it ask it twice, the input is normal it writes once but it shows twice. oddly enough it only happens on this pc not the others. I'm wondering if it's the machine or the code.

The program:

I don't see a problem that would cause this, maybe you will....

```
function uselessStars() {
    console.log("********************************************************************************");
    console.log("********************************************************************************");
    console.log("********************************************************************************");
    console.log("********************************************************************************");
    console.log("********************************************************************************");
    console.log("********************************************************************************");
}



function welcomeMSG() {
    uselessStars();
    console.log("                   WELCOME TO A GAME OF ROCK PAPER SCISSORS                     ");
    uselessStars();
}



var player1;
var player2;
var numberp1;
var numberp2;
var namep1;
var namep2;
var staygo;
var scorep1 = 0;
var scorep2 = 0;

function gameRules(player1, player2) {
    if (player1 === "rock" && player2 === "scissors" || player1 === "paper" && player2 === "rock" || player1 === "scissors" && player2 === "paper") {
        console.log("                          Congrats " + namep1 + "! You win                      ");
        scorep1 += 1;
        playAgain()
    } else if (player2 === "rock" && player1 === "scissors" || player2 === "paper" && player1 === "rock" || player2 === "scissors" && player1 === "paper") {
        console.log("                        Congrats " + namep2 + "! You win                        ");
        scorep2 += 1;
        playAgain()
    } else if (player1 === "rock" && player2 === "rock" || player1 === "paper" && player2 === "paper" || player1 === "scissors" && player2 === "paper") {
        console.log("tied");
        playAgain(namep1, namep2);
    }
}

function scoreBoard() {
    console.log("Final Scores:");
    console.log(namep1 + ": " + scorep1);
    console.log(namep2 + ": " + scorep2);
}
function associateMove(numberp1, numberp2) {
    switch (numberp1) {
        case 1:
            player1 = "paper";
            break;
        case 2:
            player1 = "rock";
            break;
        case 3:
            player1 = "scissors";
            break;
        default:
            console.log(player1 + " wrong input");
    }
    switch (numberp2) {
        case 1:
            player2 = "paper";
            break;
        case 2:
            player2 = "rock";
            break;
        case 3:
            player2 = "scissors";
            break;
        default:
            console.log(player2 + " wrong input");
    }
    console.log(player1 + " vs " + player2);
    gameRules(player1, player2)
}

const prompt = require('password-prompt');
async function Game() {
    numberp1 = await prompt(namep1 + ': press 1 for paper, 2 for rocks, 3 for scissors: ', {
        method: 'hide'
    });
    numberp2 = await prompt(' and now for ' + namep2 + ': ', {
        method: 'hide'
    });
    associateMove(parseInt(numberp1), parseInt(numberp2));
}

function exitForReal() {
    const readline = require("readline")
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question("Press any key to leave", function saveInput(staygo) {
        rl.close();
    });
}

function LunchGameNames() {
    const readline = require("readline")
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    rl.question("player 1: write your name ", function saveInput(name1) {
        rl.question("and now for player 2: ", function saveInput(name2) {
            rl.close();
            namep1 = name1;
            namep2 = name2;

            uselessStars();
            console.log("                                 TIME TO PLAY                                  ");
            uselessStars();

            Game();
        });
    });
}



function playAgain() {
    const readline = require("readline")
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    rl.question("Shall we play again ? Y - N ", function saveInput(staygo) {
        rl.close();
        if (staygo.toLowerCase() === "y") {
            if (scorep1 + scorep2 < 5) { // Continue playing until 5 rounds are completed
                Game();
            } else {
                scoreBoard();
                console.log("Game over!");
            }
        } else if (staygo.toLowerCase() === "n") {
            scoreBoard();            
        }
        exitForReal();
    });
}


welcomeMSG();
LunchGameNames();
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).